# Setting Default Value of a text Field based on the Value of a Date/Time Field in the Form (MS Access)

Tags: ms-access

I want to set the default vale of a certain field in access form that is based on a date value of another field in the same form.
For Example:-
I Have two Fields as follow:-

1. TransDate
2. FinYear

what i want is :-
*when i enter a certain date in field [TransDate], the Field [FinYear] should read the year of date that entered in [TransDate]?
Thansk in Advnce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this *ControlSource* for FinYear: `=IIf(IsNull([TransDate]), Null, Year([TransDate]))`

Comment: thanks for your help;
but if i change the control source it will not be recorded in the main table

Comment: If you store the date you don't need to store the year.